# NGINX: Retry proxy_pass for a period of time on connection refused from upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, connection-refused

I'm running NGINX 1.25.3 with the following configuration file that works well provided the upstream FCGI servers are accepting connections and responding OK:

```
upstream backend_nomad_internal2 {
        # Multiple FCGI listeners defined below
        server 127.0.0.1:42250;
        server 127.0.0.1:42251;
        server 127.0.0.1:42252;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        http2 on;

        server_name internal2.example.com;

    # BUNCH OF ssl_* CONFIG HERE

        location ~ \.fcgi$ {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html_live/;

                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_pass backend_nomad_internal2;
                fastcgi_index index.html;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*cgi)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html_live/;
        }
}
```

However, if my upstream FCGI listeners need to be restarted, they take about 15 seconds to begin accepting connections again. During this window, NGINX will instantly return HTTP error 502 to the client, which is the behaviour that I'm hoping to change.

What I would like to happen instead is for NGINX to keep trying to connect to the upstream FCGI server(s) for up to 20 seconds before returning error 502.

I've tried numerous variations such as:

```
proxy_next_upstream error;
proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
```

and

```
proxy_next_upstream error;
proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
proxy_next_upstream_timeout 30s;
```

and

```
error_page 502 503 504 = @retry;
}
location @retry {
    proxy_pass http://backend_nomad_internal2;
    proxy_next_upstream_timeout 30s;
    proxy_next_upstream error;
    proxy_next_upstream_tries 3;  # Adjust the number of retries as needed

    proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
}
```

But in all cases, the client receives an instant 502 response when the upstream FCGI servers are refusing connections.

Is there a way to configure NGINX to behave in such a way that it retries upstream connections repeatedly for up to X seconds, returning error 502 only if it can not connect within that time period?

Comment: The best solution would be to restart upstreams consequently, so they would not go offline all at once.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen - unfortunately this doesn't help because the upstream services take about 15 seconds to begin accepting connections, and during this time Nginx is instantly spitting back error 502. I would like Nginx to keep retrying for a while until the upstream services begin accepting connections again (if this is possible).

Answer (score -1):

To configure NGINX to retry upstream connections for a specified duration before returning a 502 error, you can use the proxy_next_upstream and proxy_connect_timeout directives. Below is an updated configuration that should achieve the desired behavior:

please use this code

upstream backend_nomad_internal2 {
server 127.0.0.1:42250;
server 127.0.0.1:42251;
server 127.0.0.1:42252;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
http2 on;
server_name internal2.example.com;

```
# BUNCH OF ssl_* CONFIG HERE

location ~ \.fcgi$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html_live/;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    # Use the following directives to control upstream connection behavior
    proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_timeout 20s;

    fastcgi_pass backend_nomad_internal2;
    fastcgi_index index.html;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*cgi)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 = @retry;
location @retry {
    # Retry the connection for up to 20 seconds
    proxy_pass http://backend_nomad_internal2;
    proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_timeout 20s;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html_live/;
}
```

}

In this configuration:

-> proxy_connect_timeout 2s;: Sets the timeout for establishing a connection with the upstream server to 2 seconds.

-> proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;: Specifies the conditions under which NGINX should try the next upstream server. In this case, it includes errors and timeouts.

-> proxy_timeout 20s;: Sets the maximum time allowed between the establishment of a connection and receiving the response from the upstream server. In this case, it's set to 20 seconds.

With these settings, NGINX will attempt to connect to the upstream servers for up to 20 seconds, retrying if necessary, before returning a 502 error to the client. Adjust the timeouts based on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks @ITPathSolutions, but unfortunately this doesn't work (error: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_timeout" directive is not allowed here) at the proxy_timeout lines.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).